# Stylelint - How to restrict having variables to specific files only?

Tags: css, sass, stylelint

Is it possible to give error/warning if someone in the team tries to add the variable as property (not value) in any other file other than variable.css?

it could be either CSS native variables or Sass variables

Comment: Hey Jitendra! Good day bro. I guess this would be better off to solve it in Version Control Systems than trying to enforce any constraints on CSS. What do you think?

Comment: how in version control?

Comment: Like using protected branches and manually checking stuff?

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule for that in stylelint as it is a very specific use case. The [plugin system](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/developer-guide/plugins.md) was built to accommodate these types of use cases, though. The solution is create your own plugin for your needs.